# Change root password from script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, passwords

I'm looking for a way to change a root user's password on a Linux system through a bash script, without booting the system. The only things I have found so far are to either remove the password, or to use a chroot, which I prefer not to use. 
I know how to empty the root password, but I need to change it to a different password defined earlier in the script. 
I have root access to the entire file system. 
The system is using shadow passwords, is there a way to generate an encrypted shadow password without logging in/chrooting? 
Any other ways to change the root password from script?

Comment: Some advice [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/078). There are ways. It depends on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may actually be the solution. I did not know Debian had a mkpasswd command, will try this and report back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The password hash is in `/etc/shadow`. You can simply replace it with a generated (salted) hash. The format for the password hash is described in **crypt(3)**. The default is DES, but on glibc2 systems it can contain one of several different encryption methods:

| ID | Method |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MD5 |
| 2a | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux distributions) |
| 5 | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7) |
| 6 | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7) |

So a shadow password string might look like this: `$5$saltysalt$KhboodWTnuXJ5siXvWx5mxYXbnuNJOxROfD1inCILfD`

In this case the first **$5$** part indicates it's a SHA-256 hash, the middle part is the salt and the rest is the actual hash.

To generate one, best use the system's crypt(3) function, for example with a minimal C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("%s\n", crypt(argv[1], argv[2]));
}
```

Compile with `cc mkpass.c -o mkpass -lcrypt` and then run with the plaintext password and salt string to generate a string you can put into `/etc/shadow`:

```
./mkpass yourpassword yoursalt                   # DES (default)
./mkpass yourpassword '$6$yoursalt$encrypted'    # SHA-512 (quote your $)
```

The second form may not be supported on older Linux systems. Best look at the existing string in your shadow file and use the same hash type (from the $id$ list at the top).

Answer (score -1):

Press `e` on the Ubuntu tab in the OS selection menu screen.
Update the command as following

```
rw init=/bin/bash
```

It will drop you the linux root shell.
Change your root password by simply entering command named passwd root.